# Two tables with different columns - Possible to be same height? HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

I have two tables like so. These are floated:left to appear next to each other. I would like to have table 2 the same height as table 1. As in, the yellow background goes down to the bottom of table 1.
Currently:

[image: Table]

Should look like:

[image]

I don't want to have to hard code pixels as it needs to display the same across different monitors and mobile devices.

Edit: I'll just give the last row a longer height. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Can you share some HTML and CSS?  Off the top of my head, you could make sure that both tables have the same number of entries.

Comment: Just a generic table. 6 <tr's> on left side, with 2 <td> in each. 3 <tr> on right, with 1 <td> in each. I'll try adding 3 extra <tr> on right side.

EDIT:Adding extra <tr> does not work.

Comment: Can't you make them one table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add class `.row-eq-height` to parent div:

### CSS:

```
.row-eq-height {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/dy7va6p4/2/)

Comment: Looks like the best answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can find out how many rows are in a table using this call (JavaScript, include it in a  tag):

```
var x = document.getElementById("myTable").rows.length;
```

where "myTable" is the id of your left table.

Then set the number of rows in the second table to x by getting the current number of rows:

```
var y = document.getElementById("mySecondTable").rows.length;
```

where "mySecondTable" is the id of your right table.

```
var numRowsToCreate = x - y;

for(i = 0; i < numRowsToCreate; i++) {
  var secondTable = document.getElementById("mySecondTable");
  var newRow = document.createElement('tr');
  //Set any attributes of the table row here, like background-color.

 secondTable.appendChild(newRow);
}
```

Comment: There are always going to be a static amount of rows in table 1. Can i just add <tr> x amount of times to make the amount the same?